# Which preposition follows the word 'ingredient'?

Tags: prepositions

> MSG is an **additive**(in/from/to) many foods.

> Sugar is an **ingredient**(in/from/to) most sodas

I choosed "to" as preposition for both sentences. Am I right? I have no clue how I should recognize the correct answer. For example I searched the word "ingredient" in OALD and it is the result:

> > > [image: definition of 'ingredient' in OALD]

We can see other preposition after "ingredient" in the examples.

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+additive+%2A+many&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Can%20additive%20%2A%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ban%20additive%20in%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20additive%20to%20many%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Can%20additive%20*%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ban%20additive%20in%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20additive%20to%20many%3B%2Cc0) showing that it's usually ***in*** or ***to*** after ***additive***, but ***in, of*** or ***for*** after ***ingredient***. Within that, it makes little difference which you choose.

Comment: ...[this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+ingredient+%2A+many&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Can%20ingredient%20%2A%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ban%20ingredient%20in%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20ingredient%20of%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20ingredient%20into%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20ingredient%20for%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20ingredient%20that%20many%3B%2Cc0) being the second NGram, which wouldn't fit into the first comment! It doesn't matter much anyway - for example, I don't think ***with*** would be completely ridiculous in either context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Very nice. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MSG is an additive to many foods

is not wrong. Currently however, it is not the more idiomatic choice, probably because the focus of the sentence is on the food rather than the cook or manufacturer. The manufacturer or cook added MSG **TO** the food, but the MSG is **IN** the food. Thus,

> MSG is an additive in many foods

is what is currently common today. See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=additive%20to%20food%2Cadditive%20in%20food&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadditive%20to%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadditive%20in%20food%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

> Sugar is an ingredient to most sodas

is more definitive. Using "to" with "ingredient" compared to using "in" with "ingredient" is so uncommon that it verges on or actually reaches being not idiomatic. See [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ingredient%20to%20food%2C%20ingredient%20in%20food&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cingredient%20to%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cingredient%20in%20food%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cingredient%20to%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cingredient%20in%20food%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Prepositions are slippery. Sometimes only one preposition is grammatical. Sometimes more than one preposition is grammatically acceptable, but one is strongly favored in current idiom. Some writers may distinguish slight differences in meaning with prepositions, as in "compare with" when similarities are the focus and "compare to" when differences are the focus.

Comment: I wouldn't overstate the "justification" for preferring ***in*** over ***to*** for additives. According to my NGram chart under the question, ***to*** was in fact more common for a few years around 1965. The repetition might sound a bit clunky if we "expand" to *an additive **added to** many foods* rather than *an additive **put in** many foods*, but since we're not likely to use those extended versions anyway, this doesn't really matter.

Comment: I agree. I would have been wrong 60 years ago, but I was talking about current idiom. Perhaps I should edit to piint out that there are certain contexts where “additive to” would be more idiomatic then “additive in.” For example, “The effects of chronic disease are additive to the effects of chronic malnutrition in explaining infant mortality.” Or does that just confuse things?

Comment: It's not easy to put ourselves in learners' shoes, but my feeling is too many nns mistakenly believe "the correct preposition" for any given context is far more "fixed" than it actually is. And your reference to the possibility of being "wrong 60 years ago" does rather up the ante on that front. Personally, I think if some specific usage was considered "correct" (or even just "acceptable") to *Victorian* writers, we should be very careful about classing it as incorrect today. If a usage has fallen out of favour, it's usually "dated" or "uncommon" rather than "wrong".

Comment: Good point I'll edit

Comment: I put the actual charts in your answer. Dunno if this info is useful to you, but I use the Brave browser (privacy-focused clone of Google Chrome). Using the Lightshot extension, I took screenshots of the relevant rectangles within your charts, saved them my own PC, then uploaded the saved pictures into your text.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you very much. I think your skill set with respect to software is far beyond mine.